# mysql join include the attributes in joining conditon

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join

Let i have three tables comments, attachments, descendant_comments

1. comments has many comments i.e self join
2. comments has many attachments
3. descendent_comments contains the hierarchy of comments (parent child, grand child relation)

Code:

```
SELECT comments.*, count(attachments.id)
FROM comments com
LEFT JOIN descendant_comments dc 
    ON dc.comments_id = com.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN attachments atch 
    ON (atch.comment_id = dc.child_comment_id OR atch.comment_id = com.id)
WHERE com.id = 77
```

i dont want t use the OR because it is not an optimal way to it.

there is any way to replace this line of "OR atch.comment_id = com.id"

Comment: When comments are self referencing, why do you have descendent_comment table.?

Comment: What is the structure of the tables? Can you give some sample data for the tables?

Comment: Isn't descendent_comments table redundant?  You mention that comments is self referencing, so I assume you would have `CommentId` and `ParentCommentId` columns in Comments table to link the comments to each other.

Comment: The alternative to `OR` is two queries that you combine with `UNION`.

Comment: You cannot get a meaningful `COUNT` without a `GROUP BY`; you can't add `GROUP BY` because there will be columns that are not grouped.  What are you trying to achieve??